# Android app cannot install after export

Tags: android, eclipse

When the app in the development stage, I get the apk from the "bin" file and install it in a real android phone to test the app, and it works great. However when I export the apk from the eclipse, the apk can successful export but the apk cannot install in the phone, and shows

`An existing package by the same name with a conflicting signature is already installed`

Some people said you need to uninstall the app and install it again, but this app I want to put it on the Play Store, so it is impossible to ask users to do this.

Also, I want to use the ProGuard function, so I need to export the apk to enable this function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your development APK is signed with a development key. Your production APK is signed with a production key.

When you try to install a production APK over a development APK, it detects that the keys were different and refuses to "upgrade" the APK.

For production in the Google Play store you won't have this problem. All your users are already using the production version of the app. The new APK you provide is also a production version and so since the keys match, the upgrade will work without the users needing to uninstall the app.

Comment: Thanks, And I want to know more, is it possible to find out the development key and put it in the production apk?

Comment: No you can't use the development key for a production APK. If you want to know where it's stored, look for debug.keystore (its location depends on your OS)

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall the app on your phone then re-install it